# Why are we required to self-report "Cumulative GPA as listed on your transcript"?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, united-states, gpa

As I apply to Ph.D. programs in STEM, I noticed that many online application systems require us to enter "Cumulative GPA as listed on your transcript". I wonder how my response is going to be used.

I mean, if the committee even glances at my transcript, they will surely see the GPA. Then why bother asking me? The presence of such a question makes me feel like they will filter out applicants with low GPAs based on some automated systems without even looking at their transcripts. The thing is, I am doing a much better job at graduate school (which does not list a GPA on my transcript) than at my undergraduate institute (which does). As a result, the committee will not be able to see my graduate GPA of around 4.0, but they will see I have a GPA of around 3.0 as an undergraduate, which I am afraid will leave a pretty bad first impression.

What would happen if I enter the graduate GPA even if it's not on my transcript? The concern here is that they will not be able to find the GPA on my transcript, even though it's 100% legitimate, since my graduate school simply doesn't list GPAs on the transcript. However,  I can request a separate certification of my GPA from the Registrar, so the background check won't be an issue.

Comment: Probably they have another department for computing the cumulative GPA, and the question is posed to decide whether to send the transcript to that department or not.

As far as I understood, your main concern here is whether to hide your grad GPA or not. Maybe posing the question that way might help the clarity a bit more.

Comment: @padawan I think you misunderstood my question. On the contrary, I want to expose my graduate GPA. I have edited the last paragraph to clarify.

Comment: *a pretty bad first impression* --- This from a 3.78 GPA?? Or is this a typo and you meant a 2.78 GPA? (Still higher than mine was . . .)

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I don't know man. I heard that it's easy to get a GPA of 3.9 from a U.S. institute due to GPA inflation. For example, Harvard has an average GPA of 3.8. I am among the top performers in my undergraduate institute, but my GPA seems bad compared to applicants from other institutes.

Comment: I don't know about other stem fields, but in math I suspect once a GPA of 3.75 to 3.8 is reached there's not much help a higher GPA would give, and at this point almost all attention would be paid to WHAT courses were taken (minimum required for the degree, or lots of "beyond the minimum" stuff such as graduate level courses and honors/thesis undergraduate courses), what the letters of recommendation say (big difference between "one of our best students this year" and "possibly the strongest student I've ever taught"), performance on things like Putnam exam and independent research work, etc.

Comment: FYI, I did not downvote your question. (I just noticed it got a downvote.) Maybe the downvote is because your question is too specifically tied to your own situation to be a good fit here, I don't know.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Thanks mate! The comment regarding GPA is reassuring. I think the downvotes are made by people who hate my "I am not going to play by the rule if doing so would put me at an unfair disadvantage" attitude, but your explanation also makes sense to me.

Comment: "I think the downvotes are made by people who hate my 'I am not going to play by the rule if doing so would put me at an unfair disadvantage'" ... well, yes ... because it's not unfair

Comment: When the committee sees that there are mostly A's on your graduate school transcript, they'll have an idea what your graduate school GPA is. You don't have to worry about it at all.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- To clarify, what I am seeing is that the application process forces me to hide my strong graduate GPA simply because the graduate school does not print GPAs on their transcripts. The process is essentially punishing me for an administrative decision made by the Registrar. (I know they will probably look at individual courses on the transcript, but an overall GPA surely matters, otherwise they won't ask me for it.) I am clearly at a disadvantage, and this feels unfair to me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think having a low undergraduate GPA works against you. My undergraduate GPA was lower than what you had, and I am in my last years of PhD. You can make a case in your statements that you actually improved in your graduate program.

Having said that, I suggest you enter your undergraduate GPA. You may consider these risks on not doing so:

1. By omitting information on your application (which is your undergraduate GPA in the undergraduate GPA section of the application, not in the transcript section), you are risking the system rejecting your application as incomplete.
2. By using your graduate GPA in the undergraduate GPA section, you are effectively falsifying information on your application. You are risking your admission getting voided from falsification, if you get one and someone finds out.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. Just a clarification, "using your graduate GPA in the undergraduate GPA section" is definitely not what I am suggesting! I wanted to report my graduate GPA in the graduate GPA section. I was asking since the system says I should only report my graduate GPA if it's on my graduate transcript, but it's not. However, I can request certification of my graduate GPA from the graduate Registrar.

Comment: @nalzok Sorry I misunderstood your post. I was assuming your graduate transcript would list your graduate GPA, which it seems not the case. I would follow the instructions and not put the graduate GPA because it is not on the transcript, but you may want to reach out to the department by email to make sure. You can still expose your graduate GPA in statements.